# How can i Store HTML arrays into Mysql using PHP in each columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to know how the arrays from the following HTML and Javascript can be stored in a Mysql database with each field added to the following columns inside MYSQL Database:
title, category, pdfname(the name of the files being sent from the HTML)
and the files from the HTML being stored on a directory named "pdffile" on the server
For each recordset added by the Javascript.

Below is the JAVASCRIPT code:

```js
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 if(rowCount < 10){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
 }else{
   alert("Maximum Number of Books is 10");
      
 }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
  if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
   if(rowCount <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
    alert("Cannot Remove all the Books.");
    break;
   }
   table.deleteRow(i);
   rowCount--;
   i--;
  }
 }
}
</SCRIPT>


Below is the HTML code:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
</HEAD>
    <div style="border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; background-color:red; width:100%;">
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pdf_form" method="post" name="pdf_form">

     
      <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
      <tbody>
     <p>
     <td >
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
     </td>
     <td>
     <label for="title">Title of PDF</label>
     <input type="text" id="title" name="title[]">

     
     <td>
     <label for="pdffile">PDF supported. 2MB Maximum)</label>
     <input type="file" id="pdffile" name="pdffile[]">
     
     </td>
     
     <td>
     <label for="category">Category</label>
     <select id="category" name="category[]"> 
        <option>Science</option>
        <option>Technology</option>
        <option>Biblical</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>Medical</option>
        <option>Engineering</option>
        <option>World</option>
     </select>
     </td>
     
     </p>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>


    <p> 
      <input type="button" value="Add PDF" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
      <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save PDF(s)" />
      
      <p>(All actions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
    </p>
    </form>
    </div>

    //PHP for Upload

    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
   include("session.php");
   session_start();
   
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
      
   $pdffile = $_FILES['pdffile']['name'];
   $pdffile_name = $_POST['pdffile'];
   // Get text
   $pdffile_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pdffile_name']);

   // image file directory
   $target = "books/".basename($pdfstore);  
      
$item_title = $_POST['title'];
$item_category = $_POST['category'];
$item_pdfname_name = $_POST['pdfname_name'];

foreach ($_FILES as $pdfname)

  if (move_uploaded_files($pdffile['tmp_name'], 'pdfstorage/' . $file['pdffile']))

for($count = 0; $count<count($item_title); $count++){

  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$item_title[$count]);
  $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$item_category[$count]);
  $pdfname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $item_pdfname[$count]);
  
 {
    


  $sql = "INSERT INTO pdftable (title, category, pdfname) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$pdfname')";
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'], $target));

  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<div style='border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; color:green; background-color:auto; width:100%;'> PDF with Title $title Added Successfully. </div>";
  }
  else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
  };
};
};
?>
```

Each time, the fields "Category[]" and "Title[]" are added to the database, but, the files are not moved to the "pdfstorage" folder on the server and the file names are not added to the database to.
I need the MYSQL code for successfully adding the files and the fields to the database. Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please make, and provide an attempt to achieve this yourself. We can help you with issues, but we're not here to do work for you.

Comment: _I need the MYSQL code for successfully adding the records to the database_  , any other demand ?

Comment: fyi, missing an opening `<tr>`, `<p>` not allowed inside table

Comment: @Jon Stirling. Thanks. Below is the PHP/Mysql code:

Comment: @Jon. PHP/Mysql code:  <?php
   session_start();
   
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      
      
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username[]']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password[]']);
      $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fullname[]']);
      
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fullname) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$fullname')";
      if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Added";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
};
};
?>

Comment: @SamolinaOne : Instead of writing in a comment, update your question and add properly formatted code. Instead of asking how to do, it will be better if you update with what you tried and what issues you faced

Comment: @Jon, Gadkari. The post is updated now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 if(rowCount < 10){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
 }else{
   alert("Maximum Number of Books is 10");
      
 }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
  if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
   if(rowCount <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
    alert("Cannot Remove all the Books.");
    break;
   }
   table.deleteRow(i);
   rowCount--;
   i--;
  }
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <div style="border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; background-color:red; width:100%;">
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pdf_form" method="post" name="pdf_form">

     
      <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
      <tbody>
     <p>
     <td >
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
     </td>
     <td>
     <label for="title">Title of PDF</label>
     <input type="text" id="title" name="title[]">

     
     <td>
     <label for="pdffile">PDF supported. 2MB Maximum)</label>
     <input type="file" id="pdffile" name="pdffile[]">
     
     </td>
     
     <td>
     <label for="category">Category</label>
     <select id="category" name="category[]"> 
        <option>Science</option>
        <option>Technology</option>
        <option>Biblical</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>Medical</option>
        <option>Engineering</option>
        <option>World</option>
     </select>
     </td>
     
     </p>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>


    <p> 
      <input type="button" value="Add PDF" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
      <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save PDF(s)" />
      
      <p>(All actions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
    </p>
    </form>
    </div>

    <!-- //PHP for Upload -->



    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "pdf") or die ("Error".mysqli_error($con));

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['pdffile']['size'] > 0)
 {
        $fileName = $_FILES['pdffile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['pdffile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['pdffile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['pdffile']['type'];

        $item_title = $_POST['title'];
  $item_category = $_POST['category'];

        for($count = 0; $count<count($item_title); $count++){
         

           $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$item_title[$count]);
     $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$item_category[$count]);
     $pdfname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $fileName[$count]);  //document name
     $tmpname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $tmpName[$count]);
     $folder = "uploads/";

     if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
          {
              $pdfname = addslashes($pdfname);
          }

     $doc_path = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $folder.$pdfname);

     $sql = "INSERT INTO zipcode (country, city, zipCode) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$pdfname')";

     if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo "<div style='border:auto solid 1px; font-size:15px; color:green; background-color:auto; width:100%;'> PDF with Title $title Added Successfully. </div>";
     }
     else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
     };
         }
        
    }    
}  


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can do upload without any problem. But, the problem is doing the upload alongside other fields (recordset created by the Javascript)  e.g. "title[]" and "category[]". Kindly check my modified code. Thanks.

Comment: Pokhare. i will like you to help on it, please. Thanks

Comment: @SamolinaOne Is the title and category is given by the user while uploading the pdf file?

Comment: Yes, the title[] and category[] are given by the user. Thanks.

Comment: @SamolinaOne I have edited my above answer. Take a look at it. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. I will try it out now. Thanks.

Comment: @SamolinaOne if this answer is useful to you than upvote so that it will be helpful for others also.

Comment: It works just fine. Thumbs up for you. Thank you so much.